# Anomaly Detection & ADTK- Series does not follow any known frequency

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, anomaly-detection

I have a Time series of this kind:

```
timestamp

2019-05-31 16:30:00    94.400000

2019-05-31 16:35:00    92.533333

2019-05-31 16:40:00    93.900000

2019-05-31 16:45:00    93.400000

2019-05-31 16:50:00    93.166667

...
```

I would like to use Adtk to perform unsupervised anaomaly detection. I've been resampling the historical series every five minutes, but I keep getting the same mistake.

```
temperatura27 = temperatura27.resample('5T').mean().dropna()
from adtk.detector import SeasonalAD
seasonal_ad = SeasonalAD()
anomalies = seasonal_ad.fit_detect(temperatura27)
plot(temperatura27, anomaly=anomalies, anomaly_color="red", anomaly_tag="marker")
```

```
RuntimeError: Series does not follow any known frequency (e.g. second, minute, hour, day, week, month, year, etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

you should carefully look at your data, maybe there is some missing point. For example, if there is data with a discreteness of 1 minute and the point with a time of "15:23" falls out, you will get exactly this error:
"Series does not follow any known frequency (e.g. second, minute, hour, day, week, month, year, etc."

```
2020-10-16 15:21:00,5.9357
2020-10-16 15:22:00,3.8873
2020-10-16 15:24:00,5.313
2020-10-16 15:25:00,5.5147
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking from where [vovi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64424271/1290868) left off;

If the data has missing rows, then resampling may help.

For the ***latest*** version of adtk;

```
s_train = s_train.resample("15m").sum()
```

If using an [***older***](https://github.com/arundo/adtk/issues/60) version of adtk (in its latest version, [adtk resampling is dropped](https://arundo-adtk.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/stable/releasehistory.html?highlight=resample#version-0-6-0-mar-10-2020) in [favor of](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-dataframe-resample/) [panda's](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html#pandas-dataframe-resample)), adtk has a [resampling](https://arundo-adtk.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/stable/) method;

```
from adtk.data import resample
s_train = resample(s_train, dT="15 min")
```

Comment: cutPos = np.argwhere(autocorr >= low_autocorr)[0][0]
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0